# Use older version of GCC for application that requires it

Tags: compiling, gcc, docker, chroot

The [PGI C and C++ 17.10 community edition compiler](http://www.pgroup.com/products/community.htm) does not work with Ubuntu 17.10 (at least not for code that uses OpenMP or OpenACC which is the whole point of PGI).

[According to their forum](https://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?p=22554&sid=2760ea30b52b999d885df486cf0f8da9#22554)

> According to the PGI 17.10 release notes, under "Supported Platforms", note that Ubuntu 16.10 is the newest Ubuntu we support, and gcc 6.3 is the newest gcc.
>
> We will probably get 7.2 working with 18.1, and so the Community Edition will support it in 18.4.
>
> So wait for 2 to 6 months, or install a Linux version we support.

I don't want to wait if I don't have to. **How can I get PGI 17.10 (community edition) working with Ubuntu 17.10?**

My guess is I could use something like `chroot` or Docker for this but I have never used either.

When I compile I get the error

> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/floatn.h", line 62: error: invalid argument
>             to attribute "**mode**"
>     typedef _Complex float **cfloat128 __attribute** ((**mode** (**TC**)));

So the problem I think is not just library files but also includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get it running in 17.10 .. thats what the releasenote says.

Downgrade to 16.10 or another supported version, or run 16.10 in a Virtual machine.

Comment: I'm not sure a VM will work because of the GPU offloading. I could compile in the VM and then copy the binaries over but it might rely on some libraries.  The release notes don't say you can't get it working in 17.10. It says it's not supported. I'm not convinced you can't get it working. What about chroot or Docker?

Comment: A VM works fine. It turns out the PGI does yet support `omp target` offloading anyway . If It stick to OpenACC instead of OpenMP then I don't need to use a VM anyway.